# PHP created Text does not color it should have

Tags: php, image, colors, png

the created text with **imagettftext** does have a completly other color, as it should have (mostly a color of the insertet png figure).
Why doesn't it take the color?
It must be something in the function **resizePictureAndPlaceOnSign**, because if i comment it out, it is perfect.

```
    public function resizePictureAndPlaceOnSign($filename, $new_width,  $dst_x, $dst_y){

        // create figure in memory
        $figure = imagecreatefrompng($filename);


        /* 
            CALC RATIO
        */
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

        $vh = ($height/$width);
        $new_height = $vh*$new_width;
        $rnd_new_height = round($new_height, 0); 
        /*  
        */


        // make the figure smaller
        imagecopyresampled($this->picture, $figure, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        imagedestroy($figure);

    }
    public function drawPicture()
    { 
       // $zufall = rand(1,999);


        // create picture
        $schild_leere_vorlage = imagecreatefrompng("schild_vorlage.png");
        $this->picture = imagecreate(600,192);


        // copy the image into the other image
        # int ImageCopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )
        imagecopy($this->picture, $schild_leere_vorlage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 600, 192);


            $filename = "figures/" . $_GET['figure'] . ".png";

            /*********************/
            $this->resizePictureAndPlaceOnSign($filename, 100, 25, 25);


        // create colors
        $color = 0x00000000FF;
        $color =  imagecolorallocate ($this->picture, 0, 0, 255);

        // create text
        imagettftext($this->picture, $this->fontSize , 0, 125, 100,$color , "cooperm.TTF", $this->name);


        // header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

        imagepng($this->picture);


        //$this->checkFontSize();

        imagedestroy($this->picture);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a paletted image. When you copy the other image on it you are using all available colors, so imagecolorallocate fails and sets `$color` to false.

To fix the problem do the compositing on a true color image.

```
$this->picture = imagecreatetruecolor(600,192);
```

If for some reason the output needs to be paletted, you can use [`imagetruecolortopalette()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php) to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$color =  imagecolorclosest ($this->picture, 0, 0, 255);
```

you still won't get *exactly* the pure blue, for the reasons mcrumley explained, but it could be "close enough".